# EF Core One to Many Concurrency Conflict does not throw DBConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have the following tables

```
 public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }


        public virtual ICollection<ClientFund> CompanyIncomingFunds { get; set; }
    }

  public class ClientFund
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Amount { get; set; }

        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to update client (change name) while another thread updated that specific client I get the DBConcurrencyException which works correctly.
However when Thread1 tries to update Client with Id 1 and meanwhile Thread 2 updates the Amount column of that ClientFund with ClientId = 1 I dont get the DBConcurrencyException exception and as a result THread 1 overwrites thread 2 changes.
Here are the two methods of my repository

```
public Client GetById(int Id)
        {
            return (from client in context.Client.Include(x => x.ClientFund)
                    where client.Id == Id
                    select client).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public void Update(Client client)
        {
            var existingEntity = GetById(client.Id);

            existingEntity.Name = client.Name;
            existingEntity.Description = client.Description;

            context.Entry(existingEntity).Property(x => x.RowVersion).OriginalValue = client.RowVersion;

            context.Update(existingEntity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: You don't set `ClientFund`'s rowversion to its original value, so if it ends up being marked as modified there's nothing to trigger an optimistic concurrency exception.

Comment: So you mean that I have to loop and set the RowVersion for each child entity? Imagine a scenario that I have 5000 entries for a client. Iterating and lookup each one is gonna make the update very very slow.

Comment: So far I'm only observing a fact. What you should do about it? I think it's better to prevent any `ClientFund` from getting marked as modified, f.e. don't `Include` them. Or don't use `context.Update`, because setting `existingEntity`'s properties  already marks these properties as modified.

Comment: @GertArnold This is just a sample of my actual table. I have 20 more tables like ClientFund. What is the best practise of handling them (CRUD)

Comment: Your threads are updating different entities - Thread 1 - Client and Thread 2 - ClientFund.  My understanding is RowVersion only comes into play for when the same entity is updated by different processes.  So in your instance, if both Thread 1 and Thread 2 update the same ClientFund record you will get your `DBConcurrencyException`

Comment: @pantonis I only see what you show and I've I said all I can about what I see.

Comment: See
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18505
https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/860